# How to use std::enable_if_t with perfect forwarding?

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, c++17, metaprogramming

I wrote a function receiving a variadic number of std::pairs that subtracts the 2nd element from the 1st element of each pair, and returns a tuple from the newly generated results like this:

```
template<typename... pairs, std::enable_if_t<((std::is_same_v<std::pair<int, int>, pairs>) && ...)>* = nullptr>
inline constexpr auto foo(pairs&& ...p) noexcept {
    return std::tuple((std::get<1>(std::forward<pairs>(p)) - std::get<0>(std::forward<pairs>(p)))  ...);
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto bar = foo(std::pair(4, 6), std::pair(3, 7), std::pair(1, 2));

    return 0;
}
```

This works perfectly fine. Unless I try to pass it a std::pair that isn't an rvalue, like this:

```
int main() {
    constexpr auto tup = std::pair(4, 6);
    constexpr auto bar = foo(tup, std::pair(3, 7), std::pair(1, 2));

    return 0;
}
```

If I try to do that, I get the following error:

```
no matching function for call to 'foo(const std::pair<int, int>&, std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int>)'
```

How can I pass std::pairs both as lvalue and rvalue references to this function? I'm using C++17

Comment: I am not sure, but the issue might be with `std::same_v<std::pair<int,int>, pair>` - what if it is a `std::pair<int,int>&` instead? Also, this isn't a good way to write such code. Better make it a non-template function that accepts `std::initializer_list<std::pair<int,int>>` instead of the template mess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass Lvalue, `pairs` will keep reference in its type, so

```
std::is_same_v<std::pair<int, int>, pairs>
```

results in false.

You have to discard reference for example by using `std::decay_t`:

```
std::enable_if_t<((std::is_same_v<std::pair<int, int>, std::decay_t<pairs> >) && ...)>* = nullptr
```

Answer (score 2):

When you pass an *lvalue* to the function, its corresponding type in the parameter pack is deduced as an *lvalue reference* due to how *forwarding references* work. You can use `std::decay_t` to remove all references and *cv-qualifiers* prior to your check:

```
std::enable_if_t<((std::is_same_v<std::pair<int, int>, std::decay_t<pairs>>) && ...)>
```